# How to join on concatenated columns SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables,

A segment file

```
INVNO  SEGNO  COLUMNS
00001  1      Blah
00001  2      Blah
00001  3      Blah
00002  1      Blah
00002  2      Blah
00003  1      Blah
```

and a details file

```
INVNO  SEGNO   COLUMNS
00001  1       Blah
00001  2       Blah
00001  2       Blah
00002  1       Blah
00003  1       Blah
00003  1       Blah
```

So, I need everything from both tables. What is the best practice here? My initial thought is to someone do a join on a concatenated column (concatenating INVONO & SEGNO) in both tables. I don't know how to do that but that would be my best guess. Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: Please show the results that you want.

Comment: please tag with database platform

Comment: What have you done so far???

Comment: Possible duplicate of [INNER JOIN ON vs WHERE clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018822/inner-join-on-vs-where-clause)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use multiple columns.

```
select s.invno, s.segno, s.*, d.*
from segments s join
     details d
     on d.invno = s.invno AND d.segno = s.segno
```

Comment: This is wrong -- if these are character strings it will have "false joins" eg 20 + 220 will join to 202+20.  If these are number then it will just fail.  You should never do a concatenation on a join instead use the AND operator.  It is faster AND more correct

Comment: @Hogan is correct, AND operator is better in most circumstance so I have edited my post to reflect the correct answer, sorry that was my bad

Answer (score 3):

Just join it like this.
I would spell out all the columns and not use a wild card.
But you did not tell us the columns.

```
select s.invno, s.segno, s.*, d.*
from segment s
join details d on s.invno = d.invno and s.segno = d.segno
```

Answer (score 2):

You can join on two columns:

```
select . . .   -- your columns go here
from segments s join
     details d
     on d.invno = s.invno and d.segno = s.segno
```